# handle ajax error when a user clicks refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

i apologise if this is something i should be able to look up. all of the terms i wanted were way overloaded..

here is my problem: when i open a page, it fires off a whole series of ajax calls. if i then press Shift+Refresh, all of those ajax calls are being considered errors, and showing their error message dialogs before the entire page itself reloads.

so the error is being triggered by the client - is there anyway i can find out if this is the case so i can ignore it? eg in the xmlhttprequest, or in the ajax function (i am using jquery btw)

Comment: You are putting the code inside an jQuery onLoad annonymous function right? Like, at the beginning of your code you have: $(function() { /* do all your ajax calls here */ }); You should wait until your DOM is loaded before doing ajax calls.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[this is an edit from the previous answer, which had outstanding questions that I have since resolved]

jQuery throws the error event when the user navigates away from the page either by refreshing, clicking a link, or changing the URL in the browser.  You can detect these types of errors by by implementing an error handler for the ajax call, and inspecting the xmlHttpRequest object:

```
$.ajax({
    /* ajax options omitted */
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0) 
              return;  // it's not really an error
         else
              // Do normal error handling
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as advertised. When I introduce a "real error" by disabling my network connection during a long poll, I also see readyState == 0 and status == 0.

Comment: This does not work. This method stops detecting real errors too

Comment: Restarting the web server in the middle of a long poll also yields `readyState == 0 && status == 0`. This method is not reliable.

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox. I get 404 error code and readyState has value 4

Answer (score 38):

There are several suggested approaches for detecting this:

- Several have suggested the use of a `beforeunload` handler to set a boolean flag so that the error handler can know that the page is being unloaded (See list of related/duplicated posts below). This is great, except that [mobile Safari on iOS doesn't support the `beforeunload` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad).
- [Sachindra suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15623663/345716) an approach where instead of firing the error function immediately, it got delayed a second in a `setTimeout(..., 1000)`. That way, there is a good chance the page has actually disappeared by the time the error handler gets called. "Good chance" that is. I bet if I have a huge page with e.g. many `<input>`s, it could take more than 1 sec to unload, and then perhaps the error handler would fire anyway.

I therefore suggest a combination of [reliably detecting `beforeunload` support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18137334/345716) and if `beforeunload` is not supported (*cough* iPad/iPhone *cough*) revert to Sachindra's delay trick.

See the full solution with `beforeunload` detection and all in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmorch/SyUun/).

It looks like the situation is [a little better for jQuery 2.x than for 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138362/ajax-seems-to-not-call-the-error-callback-in-jquery-2-x-e-g-due-to-page-relo), but 2.x also seems a little flakey, and so I still find this suggestion prudent.

P.S: There were also suggestions involving testing some fields in the `XHR` / `jqXHR` object. ([Here](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2009/11/30/how-to-distinguish-a-user-aborted-ajax-call-from-an-error/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1269278/345716)). I have not come accross a combination that could distinguish between user navigation and restarting the webserver during a long-running AJAX call, and I have therefore not found this approach useful to me.

This is really also an answer to these related/duplicated Stack Overflow questions:

- [jQuery AJAX fires error callback on window unload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370322/jquery-ajax-fires-error-callback-on-window-unload)
- [$.ajax calls success handler when request fails because of browser reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553124/jquery-ajax-calls-success-handler-when-request-fails-because-of-browser-reload)
- [How best to handle errors during jquery ajax calls caused by user clicking on links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850605/how-best-to-handle-errors-during-jquery-ajax-calls-caused-by-user-clicking-on-li)
- [Detecting that a jQuery.ajax call failed because the page is reloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397318/detecting-that-a-jquery-ajax-call-failed-because-the-page-is-reloading)

and these posts outside of Stack Overflow:

- [What's the proper way to deal with AJAX error because of page reload?](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-s-the-proper-way-to-deal-with-ajax-error-because-of-page-reload)
- [How to Distinguish a User-Aborted AJAX Call from an Error | I like stuff.](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2009/11/30/how-to-distinguish-a-user-aborted-ajax-call-from-an-error/)

Comment: In April of 2017, this issue now only occurs in Firefox, which does support beforeunload.

Answer (score 6):

```
var isPageBeingRefreshed = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    isPageBeingRefreshed = true;
};

$.ajax({
    error: function (xhr, type, errorThrown) {
        if (!xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()) {
            xhr.abort();
            if (isPageBeingRefreshed) {
                return; // not an error
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This *almost* worked for me. It worked in Firefox, Chrome, IE8, IE10 and on Android's stock browser. [But **not** in iOS's Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127621/is-there-any-way-to-use-window-onbeforeunload-on-mobile-safari-for-ios-devices). An improvement suggestion (that still doesn't work in Safari/iOS) would be to use `$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {...})` instead of `window.beforeunload = function () {...}` so as not to hijack/hog the beforeunload handler. Still looking for something that also works in iOS Safari too.

Answer (score 2):

The above techniques does not work for a periodically refreshing page (for example every half seconds). I have figured out that the error caused by refreshing the page can be avoided using delaying the error handling process by a small amount of time.

Example:

```
$.ajax(...)
.success(...)
.error(function(jqXHR) {
setTimeout(function() {
  // error showing process
}, 1000);
});
```

In addition to that

> window.onbeforeunload =  function() {//stop ajax calls}

event can be used for less frequently refreshing ajax calls.

Answer (score 2):

Combined version of <kbd>nisanth074</kbd> and <kbd>Peter V. Mørch</kbd> answers, that worked for me.

**Example:**

```
var isPageBeingRefreshed = false;

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){

    isPageBeingRefreshed = true;
});

$.ajax({

    // Standart AJAX settings

}).error(function(){

    if (!isPageBeingRefreshed) {

        // Displaying error message
    }
});
```