# How to show a confirm box on closing a tab or hiting back button on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, mobile-browser

I have a web app and I want to avoid that someone accidentally press the back button on the phone, losing all the javascript data that was produced. I tried the `window.onbeforeunload` aproach. It works at the desktop, but not in the phone.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903457/is-the-onbeforeunload-event-not-supported-on-iphone

Comment: It might not be possible. I'm certain about Iphone but it may work in Android, can't say for sure. 
Just add events on all the exit links (buttons, links etc) and save the data.