# how to know close mobile web brower?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I know mobile web browser & app close?
I using local Storage for make auto login in my mobile Web. when I set auto login function is `false` and than close mobile web browser in my iphone and restart browser. It's still login `true` in local storage. I don't know exactly how can I know mobile web browser close.

just upload my code like this

```
autoLogin button check -> localStorage.autoLogin = "true" 

autoLogin button not check -> localStorage.autoLogin = "false"
```

Comment: there isn't an event for that.

Comment: You'd be looking for the `onbeforeunload` event, but it is [not supported on some mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903457/is-the-onbeforeunload-event-not-supported-on-iphone) (and desktop browsers that do support it will limit what you're allowed to do in that event handler, due to too many bad actors abusing it to force windows to stay open or cause other annoyances.)