# javascript jquery calling php not working on iPhone/Ipad

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ipad, duration

I've been working on the following code today and it works quite nicely on my local machine. But when I test it on my iPhone/iPad it doesn't work at all.

The code is supposed to save the duration of the page visit to a text file when the user leaves the website. I know there are a lot of alternative scripts for download on the internet, but I want to write this myself. Any suggestions are welcome.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<HEAD>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       function unloadPage(){

       var dd = new Date();
       var hh = (dd.getHours()<10?'0':'') + dd.getHours();
       var mm = (dd.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + dd.getMinutes();
       var ss = (dd.getSeconds()<10?'0':'') + dd.getSeconds();
       var htmlString="<?php echo date('Gis') ?>";
       var timed = (hh + "" + mm + "" + ss) - htmlString;

       jQuery.ajax({
         url:    'time2.php?t=' + timed,
         success: function(result) {
                      if(result.isOk == false)
                          alert(result.message);
                  },
         async:   false
       });          
       }

       window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;

    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>thepaintjob.nl</title>
</head>
<BODY>
    <? 
            $myFile = "temp.txt";
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
            $theData = fread($fh, 5);
            fclose($fh);
            echo duration($theData);
    ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
    function duration($secs) 
    { 
        $vals = array('w' => (int) ($secs / 86400 / 7), 
                      'd' => $secs / 86400 % 7, 
                      'h' => $secs / 3600 % 24, 
                      'm' => $secs / 60 % 60, 
                      's' => $secs % 60); 

        $ret = array(); 

        $added = false; 
        foreach ($vals as $k => $v) { 
            if ($v > 0 || $added) { 
                $added = true; 
                $ret[] = $v . $k; 
            } 
        } 

        return join(' ', $ret); 
    } 
?>
```

time2.php:

```
<?php
$myFile = "temp.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, 5);
fclose($fh);
echo $total = $theData+$_GET['t'];



 $File = "temp.txt";
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
 $Data = $total;
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
 fclose($Handle); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't `var timed = (hh + "" + mm + "" + ss) - htmlString;` raise an error? You can't subtract strings, can you?

Comment: Where exactly does your script fail? Do you get ay errors?

Comment: well i didn't get any errors in safari or chrome. it seems to work, i already have over 15 minutes of "watch" time on my website :)

Answer (score 3):

iOS doesn't support `onbeforeunload`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127621/is-there-any-way-to-use-window-onbeforeunload-on-mobile-safari-for-ios-devices) addresses this issue.