# onbeforeunload workaround for mobile safari?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, onbeforeunload

I need the user to confirm that she/he really wants to leave and that their data is not saved. onbeforeunload works perfect for that situation but I just found out that its not supported on mobile safari. Is it possible to achieve the same effect on any other way on iPhone/iPad?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to use window.onbeforeunload on Mobile Safari for iOS devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127621/is-there-any-way-to-use-window-onbeforeunload-on-mobile-safari-for-ios-devices)