# beforeunload event is not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I want to clear session value or remove session value when a user leaves a particular page. For that I had written this condition, it works in all browsers except Safari.

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function()
{
   $.session.remove('visited');
});
```

Is there an alternative in Safari?

Comment: Why aren't you using `onunload` event handler which is non intrusive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to use window.onbeforeunload on Mobile Safari for iOS devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127621/is-there-any-way-to-use-window-onbeforeunload-on-mobile-safari-for-ios-devices)

Comment: @Arjun, do you know what error you might be receiving when you try your code in Safari? I am curious whether the "beforeunload" event is failing, or if it is the "window.sessionStorage" call that is not supported, or if it is something else.

Answer (score 2):

beforeunload is for javascript window object , not for jquery $window object.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // the absence of a returnValue property on the event will guarantee the browser unload happens
 console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: I added window.addEventListener, here the issue is, it works fine for all browsers except for safari. In safari it keeps on loading continuously.

Comment: I suggest use New browser events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/1.5/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching#New_browser_events

Answer (score 1):

Can you refer the following links, it may be help you to understand.

https://webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/

**Load/Unload Event Handlers :**

Web developers can make use of the load and unload events to do work at certain points in the lifetime of a web page.

The purpose of the load event is quite straightforward: To perform initial setup of a new page once it has loaded.

The unload event is comparatively mysterious. Whenever the user leaves a page it is "unloaded" and scripts can do some final cleanup.

The mysterious part is that "leaving the page" can mean one of a few things:

1. The user closes the browser tab or window, resulting in the
   destruction of the visible page.
2. The browser navigates from the old page to a new page, resulting in
   the destruction of the old visible page.

The Page Cache makes this even more interesting by adding a new navigation possibility:

3. The browser navigates from the old page to a new page, but the old
   visible page is suspended, hidden, and placed in the Page Cache.

Some existing stack answers also available for this :

[window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload is not working in Firefox , Safari , Opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o)