# Is there a reliable cross browser way to capture page navigation/reload/close?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onbeforeunload

I simply want to save current state of my PWA in IndexedDB before leaving the page (when the user navigates to a new page, reloads the same page, or closes the tab/browser). But to my surprise, there is no reliable way to do this that works in all major browsers.

I've tested to capture `window.onunload`, `window.onbeforeunload`, `window.onpagehide`, `window.onblur` and `document.onvisibilitychange`. I can cover almost all cases, but not page reload on iOS Safari.

There are plenty of posts about this problem on Stackoverflow. Is there still no solution?

```js
window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
  save();
});

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
  save();
});

window.addEventListener(
  'pagehide',
  function () {
    save();
  },
  false,
);

window.addEventListener('blur', function () {
  save();
});

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
  save();
});
```

Comment: Maybe `document.pagehide`. `blur` should be working. [Is there any way to use window.onbeforeunload on Mobile Safari for iOS devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127621/is-there-any-way-to-use-window-onbeforeunload-on-mobile-safari-for-ios-devices)

Comment: Come to think of it, you should probably just be storing state every time a meaningful change happens rather than waiting until unload.

Comment: @Ouroborus Thanks for the suggestions. When you press the page reload button on Safari for iOS (iPhone) there is no pagehide or blur event. If there was a way to detect the browser reload button, it would solve my problem. I have lots of data, and want to avoid saving it for every small change the user makes, because it will slow down the app.

Comment: No, there's no way to detect such a thing directly, before it actually happens, it needs to be inferred as you're doing. I have doubts that it would slow the app down as the IndexedDB API is asynchronous. If you'd need to update the database rapidly (more than, say, a few times a second), I would suggest re-examining what parts of state you actually need to save in preparation for a page reload.

Comment: `onbeforeunload` will be triggered on reload with Google Chrome.