# $.ajax seems to not call the error: callback in jQuery 2.x e.g. due to page reloads. Fantastic! But why?

Tags: jquery

I've seen in jQuery 1.10.1 that if an `$.ajax` request is underway when a page unload occurs (e.g. due to user clicking a link or reloading the page), the `error:` callback is called.

That seems not be the case in jQuery 2.0.0 or 2.0.2. And that is **fantastic**.

There are 7 questions at least here on SO, that ask about `error:` being called when navigating. E.g. [handle ajax error when a user clicks refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699941/handle-ajax-error-when-a-user-clicks-refresh)

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmorch/TJ3zs/) - it starts out running 1.10.1 but you can change it to 2.0.2 in the controls on the left. Essentially:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/json/",
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            a: 23
        }),
        delay: 30
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (json) {
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(json));
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error callback called");
    }
});
```

Notice how the alert is shown for 1.10.1 but not for 2.0.2.

However, I don't see anything in the ["jQuery 2.0 Released" announcement](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/) to that effect.

Can I rely on this being fixed/changed or is this an accident that could be browser-dependent or something? It seems to have been fixed at least in Chromium and mobile Safari (iPad).

I'm looking for a source of the fix, so I can see if I can get 1.x to stop calling the error handler or at least detect in the error callback whether this is due to user action / navigation. Especially because the best solution I've seen so far is to use `beforeunload` to detect page unload at the time of the `error:` callback. Problem is, that [`beforeunload` doesn't work in mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad).

FWIW: I'm testing on Ubuntu linux 12.04.

**Edited**: to remove claim that it also was fixed for Firefox. It isn't.

Comment: can't reproduce your problem, the alert is shown for both jquery versions under chrome Version 28.0.1500.95 m

Comment: That is strange. I see a difference in behavior in all of (FF, Chrome, mobile safari). My Chromium is `Version 28.0.1500.71 Ubuntu 12.04 (28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.12.04.1)` - seen from chrome://chrome/

Comment: ARRHH... Sorry, I now discover that FF still calls the error: callback with 2.0.2. But at least now Chrome and mobile safari do not. That is still true.

Comment: just checked again - chrome does report the error in both cases ... i'm on win 7, however ... still strange