# window.onbeforeunload not working on the iPad?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, onbeforeunload

Does anyone know if the `onbeforeunload` event is supported on the iPad and/or if there's a different way to use it?

I've tried pretty much everything, and it seems like the `onbeforeunload` event is never triggered on the iPad (Safari browser).

Specifically, this is what I've tried:

- `window.onbeforeunload = function(event) { event.returnValue = 'test'; }`
- `window.onbeforeunload = function(event) { return 'test'; }`
- (both of the above together)
- `window.onbeforeunload = function(event) { alert('test')'; }`
- (all of the above functions but inside `<body onbeforeunload="...">`

All of these work on FF and Safari on the PC, but not on the iPad.

Also, I've done the following just after loading the page:

```
alert('onbeforeunload' in window);
alert(typeof window.onbeforeunload);
alert(window.onbeforeunload);
```

Respectively, the results are:

- `true`
- `object`
- `null`

So, the browser does have the property, but for some reason it doesn't get fired.

The ways I try to navigate away from the page are by clicking the back and forward buttons, by doing a google search in the top bar, by changing location in the address bar, and by clicking on a bookmark.

Does anyone have any idea about what's going on? I'd greatly appreciate any input.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you both for your input. It must be one of the reasons you mentioned. Unfortunately, there's no official documentation from Apple regarding this and other limitations. Hopefully, they will come up with a more creative way of enabling this feature, while preventing malicious use of it. I hear very often that people accidentally tap away from the page and lose all the data they had entered in a form.

Comment: Have you tried using `addEventListener()`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `beforeunload` doesn't work on Safari on iOS. :-( Perhaps not what you're looking for, but I have a suggestion for how to [reliably test for a working `beforeunload`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18137334/345716)

Comment: On Mar 3'16, The ```window.onbeforeunload = function(event) { event.returnValue = 'test'; }``` doesn't work on both Chrome and Safari of iOS 9.2.1 . I really like ```onbeforeunload``` Because the page does not change if I click cancel.

Comment: Seems like this problem was solved in Safari and iOS 13

Comment: @Finesse, I just tested it on Safari with iOS 15, and the problem is still present.

Answer (score 27):

This bit of JavaScript works for me on Safari and Chrome on ipad and iphone, as well as desktop/laptop/other browsers:

```
var isOnIOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
var eventName = isOnIOS ? "pagehide" : "beforeunload";

window.addEventListener(eventName, function (event) { 
    window.event.cancelBubble = true; // Don't know if this works on iOS but it might!
    ...
} );
```

Comment: It can catch the event, but how can you pop up the confirmation prompt? Using `return 'test';` similar to that by op isn't working..

Comment: Thanks I missed that in the original question. I haven't specifically tested this on iOS, but possibly adding this additional line would work:      window.event.cancelBubble = true;
I'll add to my answer

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it does not work...
I tried to put alert() inside it, seems the new page has begun to load before the alert() is fired. Also see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad

Comment: @user2335065 did you find any solution for the same.

Comment: guys, did you find any solution to show the confirmation prompt before leaving page? This works fine in every browser except IOS safari. I tried pagehide event too, but didn't work for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tested multiple workarounds and I'm pretty sure it's not possible to show the  confirmation prompt when on iOS, regardless of the browser used.

Comment: var eventName = !!isOnIOS ? "pagehide" : "beforeunload" to avoid always TRUE

Answer (score 20):

I have found that the onunload() event does fire. It's behavior is somewhat odd; whatever you have in your callback function attached to the event is actually run after the new page has loaded in the background (You can't tell it's loaded yet, but server logging will show that it has).

More oddly, if you have a confirm() call in your onunload(), and the user has clicked a link to go somewhere else, you are in business. If, however, the user closes the iPad Safari browser tab, the onunload() event will fire, but your confirm() will have an implicit cancel as response.

Comment: Huh, seems this confirm quirk (that the second page is hit before the confirm message) is true not just for mobile safari but for firefox (and probably others) as well. You just blew my mind.

Comment: `unload` event deprecated in favor of `pagehide` see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5

Comment: @sol0mka: That’s it, man! Great! In my case the following code did the job, so far as I can see for all my browsers AND iOS: $(window).on('beforeunload pagehide', function() {
 // my stuff that has to be done on page change
} ); This should be the accepted answer in my eyes.

Comment: It shoud be noted that, under certain conditions, the unload, beforeunload and pagehide events may not fire reliably by the browser. For example, pagehide will not fire if a mobile user closes the browser app via the app manager. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event

Answer (score 6):

Only Apple would know for sure, but my guess is that they purposely did not enable that functionality in mobile Safari because it is most often used by shady characters to get you to stay on their site or pop up lots of porn/advertising windows.

Comment: Or, you know, save your changes automatically so they aren't lost just because you accidentally tapped the wrong thing.

Comment: I didn't say there weren't valid uses, I just said that those were the most often uses.

Comment: @JoelMueller Your comment should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: @JoelMueller That is exactly my use case. Grrr @ apple

Comment: @JoelMueller can you please share any official doc where we can address this statement that mobile safari saves changes automatically.

Comment: If that's why they don't support "beforeunload" what do you suppose their reason for supporting "pagehide" is?
Maybe they're invested in StackOverflow and just wanted to force more people onto this site to figure this out...

Comment: @NeerajRathod probably too late but what he meant was window.onbeforeunload can be used to save changes automatically if user accidentally closed the tab and you got it wrong

Answer (score 3):

There's a [known bug in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19324) with onbeforeunload. I believe it's fixed in the latest beta of Chrome 5, but it's quite possible the iPad's browser is made from a version of WebKit that doesn't have the fix.

[Related Chrome bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4422).

Comment: I'm I confused or does this bug still exist on the iPad browser?

Answer (score 3):

beforeunload event is not supported by Mobile Safari. You can see the list of all supported events here: [Handling Events Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5)

And the beforeunload is not in the list!

Answer (score 2):

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=97035

see hear.

> alerts are no longer allowed during page dismissal events (beforeunload, unload, pagehide).

I think alerts, prompt, confirm, and other actions like these are also no longer allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that should work on all modern browsers:

```
var unloaded = false;
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e)
{
    if (unloaded)
        return;
    unloaded = true;
    console.log("beforeUnload");
});
window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(e)
{
    if (document.visibilityState == 'hidden')
    {
        if (unloaded)
            return;
        unloaded = true;
        console.log("beforeUnload");
    }
});
```

Mobile browsers don't tend to not support `beforeunload` because the browser can go into the background without unloading the page, then be killed by the operating system at any time.

Most desktop browser contain a bug that causes `visibilityState` to not get called when the document unloads. See: [here](https://www.igvita.com/2015/11/20/dont-lose-user-and-app-state-use-page-visibility/).

Therefore, it's important to include both events to cover all scenarios.

**NB**

I have used `console.log` instead of `alert` in my example because `alert` will get blocked by some browsers when called from `beforeunload` or `visibilitychange`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know if the page has been left you can use `document.unload`. It works fine in ios browsers. If you see on [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5) you'll find that it's deprecated and they recommend to use document.pagehide

Comment: yes, this event fires in safari, but confirmation prompt is not coming as in chrome.