# jquery beforeunload does not display message

Tags: jquery, onbeforeunload

The jsfiddle for this is at http://jsfiddle.net/whDm6/18/

If I uncomment the Alert in the following code, change a form value, and refresh the page, it displays an alert. So I know the code is executing up to that point. But if I leave the Alert commented out it does not display the beforeunload box like I expect it to.

I have tried using bind and also using a basic window.onbeforeunload = function() {} without binding it with Jquery but none of those worked.

Using Jquery 1.8.2

```
var currentUlValues = {};
currentUlValues['input1'] = "red";
currentUlValues['input2'] = "blue";
needToConfirm = true;

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    if (needToConfirm) {
        $.each(currentUlValues, function(key, value) {
            var elem = $("#"+key).val();
            if (typeof elem !== 'undefined') {
                if (elem != currentUlValues[key]) {
                    //alert(elem + " - " + currentUlValues[key]);
                    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

HTML Form

```
<form>
    <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" value="red" />
    <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text" value="blue" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are return form the callback function of `.each`, which is in wrong scope, you should return the string outside it.

***[The working demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/whDm6/19/)***

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    var is_return = false;
    if (needToConfirm) {
        $.each(currentUlValues, function(key, value) {
            var elem = $("#"+key).val();
            if (typeof elem !== 'undefined') {
                if (elem != currentUlValues[key]) {
                    is_return = true;
                    // here return false is to stop the iterate
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        if (is_return) {
            return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
        }
    }
});
```

​

Comment: The message is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

The `return` is return-ing the `$.each` anonymous function instead of the `beforeunload` function

Comment: Sorry - that just tells you what the problem is - not a solution. Try and set a variable at the top of the beforeunload function() and if it is changed by the $.each function then return otherwise nothing

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here [Dialog box runs for 1 sec and disappears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063522/jquery-beforeunload)
Short saying:

> beforeunload utilizes a method built in to the browser, you need to
>   return a string to it, and the browser will display the string and ask
>   the user if they want to leave the page.
>
> You cannot use your own dialog boxes (or jQueryUI modal dialogs) to
>   override beforeunload.

Comment: return 'Are you sure you want to leave?'; is a string.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use

```
return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?');
```