# how to get redirecting page url using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I want to get a url of the page where user is going after reaching to my webpage. Let say user just came to my website page xyz and now he entered the another url abc  on the browser bar. So now i want to get a link of abc using jquery or javascript. Is it possible?

Comment: I certainly hope that is not possible. It would be a privacy violation imho.

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to do that, it's a security violation.

Comment: *"where user is going after reaching to my webpage"* - is the user leaving your webpage by clicking or link or by entering a new address in the browser bar?

Comment: by entering a new address in the browser bar. actually i want to show user alert message with a redirecting url.

Answer (score 1):

Because it can't be done. The new location is private/sensitive information. Nobody wants you to know which sites they visit when they leave your site.

[How can i get the destination url in javascript onbeforeunload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event)

But if you want to do something before unload than you can get help from below link.

[jquery beforeunload does not display message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063563/jquery-beforeunload-does-not-display-message)

You got help from this

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){
});
```