# Capture browser event and redirect to login page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to capture browser events such as refresh, close, back button press. If any of these events occur I need to redirect to Login.aspx page. I have tried the following code but it does not work for pop up too.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">     
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?  You will lose any unsaved data.';
    };
</script>
```

What do I need to do to Redirect to Login.aspx page on refresh or back button press or close button press of the browser?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do since your example doesn't seem to try do the same as your description. But have you tried using `window.location.href = "https://www.google.se"`?

Answer (score 0):

May this can help you.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () { // escape function context
        window.location = 'Login.aspx';
    }, 0);
    window.onbeforeunload = null;   // necessary to prevent infinite loop
                                    // that kills your browser
    return 'Press "Stay On Page" to go to current page!';
        // pressing leave will still leave, but the GET may be fired first anyway
}
```

[Refrence code :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747044/beforeunload-is-not-working-to-redirect-user-to-another-page-how-can-i-redirect)

Comment: Actually I have the login.aspx inside security folder. And i have the home.aspx in home folder. If i use the above code. I get the url as localhost/home/login.aspx so it shows error. But the required url is localhost/security/login.aspx

Comment: So you can follow your URL where I put Login.aspx.

Comment: try to change the following URL as you want. There I used this as an example.