# when unload or exit event execute a function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a customize pop up box like a lightbox or a modal box and I want to show it and prevent the page from unloading or exit when a user tries to leave or exit the page so heres my code and my try so far:

```js
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  return loadPopup();
});
```

As you can see from the above codes, when a user tries to exit or leave the page, it should execute a function:

```js
loadPopup();
```

But it does not work, the `loadPopup();` doesn't fired. What supposed to be a problem on my above codes why it doesnt execute the `loadPopup();` function?

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063522/jquery-beforeunload.

`beforeunload` doesn't work like you want it to; it just takes a string (if you return one) and pops that up. You can do *some* stuff on `unload`, though. Again, see the linked answer.

Comment: What does `loadPopup` do/return?  The *only* thing you can return from `beforeunload` is a string.  It also will *NOT* wait for any async functions or callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Cnsyd/

I am not sure you do something using jQuery, but obviously you can do something with javaScript.

```
 function closeIt()
  {
    return "Any string value here forces a dialog box to \n" + 
         "appear before closing the window.";
  }
  window.onbeforeunload = closeIt;
```

JavaScript [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event. It's introduced by Microsoft, but works in most browsers and click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Believes this is the thing ultimately you requires.

Comment: definetly the same answer as others as well and doesnt give accurate respond to my post!

Comment: @JuliverGalleto what you are trying with LoadPopUp ? Did you try the way I suggested. if possible can you please post your code into jsfidldle,

Comment: will i get used of your answer, I use it in other way and in alternative concept. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

VeeKayBee solution is correct.

Anyway you can do this with JQuery too:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
             fireOnLeave();
             return '';
});
function fireOnLeave(){
    console.log('Fired');  
}
```

You can check the console log and see 'Fired' string which is confirming that the function has been fired.But you **have** to return a string to 'beforeunload' event.

And also jquery .unload do the thing but it has been deprecated since JQuery 1.8
http://api.jquery.com/unload/