# Display of modal popup form when users tries to close the tab instead of logout option

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm displaying a modal popup with small  feedback form whenever the user logs off from the application. But the problem is whenever the user directly closes the tab instead of logout then I  want user to fill this form and then close the tab of the browser using jquery. I used window. Unload but getting alert blocked error in console.. Any alternative way to achieve display of modal window on close of tab??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open a custom popup on browser window/tab close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263277/open-a-custom-popup-on-browser-window-tab-close)

Comment: But when I use this onbefore unload.. I'm getting leave or stay alert only.. even I called the modal window function.. And on click of leave, tab is automatically closing without showing my modal window form