# Confirmation before leaving/closing of tab?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show a confirmation pop before user close the tab or went to another tab like facebook, gmail, GoDaddy & others do.

My code working for Firefox but not for other browser like chrome, safari etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var hook = true;
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if (hook) {
          return "Did you save"
        }
      }
      function unhook() {
        hook=false;
      }
    </script>
```

Call unhook() onClick for button and links

```
<a href="http://example.com" onClick="unhook()">No Block URL</a>
```

Please help me to get this fixed.

Comment: Do you know the modal? Do you want modal like this?https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confirmation before closing of tab/browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser)

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: It's already asked please check below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263277/open-a-custom-popup-on-browser-window-tab-close

Comment: It's already asked please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263277/open-a-custom-popup-on-browser-window-tab-close

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) of `window.beforeunload()`, you can see that, though widely the basic unload event is supported, a custom message can only be set in internet explorer and certain versions of some browsers. So just use the normal standard message.

> This feature (custom messages) was often exploited by malicous sites to interact with user in a harmful or malipulative way. This is why many browsers don't support this anymore, until some patch removes the threat for users.

Standard message solution:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide me a code with standard message which support all browser.

Comment: Firefox displays the string: "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." 
Chrome displays the string: "Do you want to leave this site? Changes you made may not be saved."

Comment: Depends solely on the browser

Comment: it working for Firefox with standard message but not for other browser like chrome, safari, IE, Edge etc

Comment: Have you read the example from the link i provided? I will edit my question with the code provided by microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Ouibounce](https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce/blob/master/source/ouibounce.js) it helps detect when a user is about to leave the page(It looks at the position of the cursor). You could probably build off this library.