# Showing alert box on `beforeunload` event

Tags: jquery

I want to show an alert box on the `beforeunload` event. I am using the following code for that.
Problem with this, is that it does not show an alert box on this event.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
                alert($(location).attr('hostname'));
            });
```

How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065085/1777090). You can use `unload` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  return location.host;
});
```

This is what you have to do.

Basically you can also use without jquery

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){ return location.hostname; };
```