# Stopping the user from navigating away using `window.onbeforeunload`

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display an alert when the user clicks the **back**, **forward** or **refresh** browser buttons, but I am not getting the desired output...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(displayAlert());
    function displayAlert() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            return "Are you sure want to LOGOUT the session ?";
        };
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, the document.ready here is pointless. `displayAlert` is always immediately invoked. I think you meant `$(document).ready(displayAlert);`, but I'm not sure why you would wait for the DOM to become ready before attaching the event handler.

Comment: [`Working Example`](http://jsbin.com/wuhejujotu/1/edit?output) and solution details here [`window.onbeforeunload`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21455923/769678). Hope it helps!

Comment: @Shubh yes this works,thankyou. But I just copy pasted,can u explain what is happening? Sorry I dont know javascript.

Answer (score 2):

[`WindowEventHandlers.onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) The unload event is raised when the window is unloading its content and resources. The resources removal is processed after the unload event occurs.

```
window.onunload = funcRef;
```

[`WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) An event that fires when a window is about to unload its resources. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

IE has issues with `onload` event and Opera has with `onbeforeunload`. So to reach to a solution which would handle both the situations I came across `user3253009` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21455923/769678)

```
/*Code Start*/
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable

myEvent(chkevent, function(e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
    var confirmationMessage = 'Cookies for you.. If you stay back!!?'; // a space
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage;
});
/*Code End*/
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/37edab3be105e3a36975). Hope it helps!

### Update

If you want to show a Bootstrap Modal when user is navigating away from you page,then you can try something like below:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#cancel_modal').modal('show');
};
```

Comment: Why does the confirmationMessage appear twice?

Comment: Can I convert this into a bootsrap modal?

Comment: For Bootstap Modal window you could try something like `$('#my-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6671he8g/)

Comment: Your demo is a different one, it is not for window.onbeforeunload alert

Comment: @sumedha: The reason behind this approach is `onbeforeunload` gets triggered when a `window` is unloading its content and resources. The bootstrap modal window is not a `window` object, so the `onbeforeunload` would not be of much help!. ***Its my understanding though!*** You can raise a different question for more clarifications.

Comment: so are you saying its not possible to display the alert using a bootstrap modal? I tried using the code above given by you and replaced the confirmationMessage string with `$('#cancel_modal').modal('show');` where #cancel_modal is the id for `<div>` of bootstrap modal, but the o/p was that it showed me both, the windows event alert as well as bootstrap modal.

Comment: Oh! Were you meaning that you want to display a Bootstrap Modal window when user navigates away from the page?

Comment: Yes, I want to display a bootstrap modal when the user tries to navigate away

Comment: Please update your question and create a [Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that it can refect your current problem.

Comment: try this `window.onbeforeunload = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#cancel_modal').modal('show');
    };`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74340/discussion-between-shubh-and-sumedha).

Comment: I don't think so it is possible [help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065085/769678)