# How to display a bootstrap modal for window.onbeforeunload alert?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display a twitter bootstrap modal when the user clicks the back,forward or refresh browser button,but I am not getting the desired o/p.This is what I tried :

```
    @section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            return $('#cancel_modal').modal('show');
        }
    </script>
}
```

and called it in the body :

```
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
```

Note: #cancel_modal is the id of the `<div>` where bootstrap modal is defined.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. Please see this SO question for more information. [Dialog box runs for 1 sec and disappears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063522/dialog-box-runs-for-1-sec-and-disappears/6065085#6065085)