# Custom JavaScript alert not stopping page from closing

Tags: javascript

I'm using the custom alert below when page is about to close. The issue is that the alert pups up and the page closes before the user can click the OK button on the custom alert. What is missing is the custom alert that it cannot keep the page open till the user clicks the OK button?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   {
      return custom_alert(head, txt);
   }


function custom_alert(head, txt) {
  var d = document;
  var c_obj = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
  c_obj.id = "contain";
  c_obj.style.height = d.documentElement.scrollHeight + "px";
  var alertObj = c_obj.appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
  alertObj.id = "alert";
  if (d.all && !window.opera)
    alertObj.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px";
  alertObj.style.left = (d.documentElement.scrollWidth - alertObj.offsetWidth) / 2 + "px";
  alertObj.style.visiblity = "visible";
  var h1 = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("h1"));
  h1.appendChild(d.createTextNode(head));
  var msg = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
  msg.innerHTML = txt;
  var btn = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("a"));
  btn.id = "close";
  btn.appendChild(d.createTextNode('ok'));
  btn.focus();
  btn.onclick = function() {
    c_obj.parentNode.removeChild(c_obj);
  };
  alertObj.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: No, you are only creating a dom object (here a div) that mimicks the [window.confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/confirm) modal dialogue. This last does block execution of the program, yours doesn't

Comment: onbeforeunload is the only thing - you can't block anything with anything in the DOM.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('beforeunload',function(e){e.preventDefault();})` for example asks the user whether to close this page that could contain unsaved data.

Comment: You can not show custom dialog. [Here][1] is a good explanation.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063522/dialog-box-runs-for-1-sec-and-disappears/6065085#6065085

Answer (score 0):

I found a library that solves this problem:

http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

The offical alert: `alert("Oops... Something went wrong!");`

The changed alert: `sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");`

This library solves many of the problems of creating your own alert.