# Onbeforeunload event support on iPad

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, safari, onbeforeunload

Is onbeforeunload event supported on iPad Safari ? If no, is there any alternate way to detect window closing on iPad ? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad), and there are is some anecdotal evidence to say that it does work in some circumstances.

Comment: Yes, i already saw that..But it does not have a cLear answer..

Comment: Do u have a clear answer if the event is supported ?

Comment: From the FAQ: "exact duplicate
This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question."

Comment: @stef: Where did you see "anecdotal evidence to say that it does work in some circumstances"? The [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad) mentions that `onunload` fires, but not that `onbeforeunload?  does. I otherwise completely agree that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Sorry it was two years ago and I can't remember!