# Detecting form changes on beforeunload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This has already been asked, I know, but I don't understand why this isn't working for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/M9tnP/16/

Trying to detect form changes, and if the user tries to navigate away, I want them to confirm that they will lose their changes...

```
var dirty = false;
$("form#add_item :input").change(function() {
    dirty = true;
});

$("window").on('beforeunload', function() {
    if (dirty) {
        return 'You have unsaved changes! If you leave this page, your changes will be lost.';
    }
```

});​

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the event handler for `onbeforeunload` directly on the `window` object:

```
var dirty = false;
$("form#add_item :input").change(function() {
    //alert("form changed!")
    dirty = true;
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (dirty) {
        return 'You have unsaved changes! If you leave this page, your changes will be lost.';
    }
};​
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/M9tnP/20/**

Comment: Did you edit the text box first? I'm using Chrome 21 as well.

Comment: And when you click 'Leave Page' remember that it re-directs you to your old jsFiddle revision. You need to make sure you're viewing revision 18 http://jsfiddle.net/M9tnP/18/

Comment: This is not true: "You need to set the event handler for onbeforeunload directly on the window object". `$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {...})` (without the quotes) works fine, and is preferable to assigning `window.onbeforeonload`, because now several can subscribe to the `beforeonload` event!

Comment: A minor note - perhaps you don't care: Beware that [beforeunload doesn't work on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad).

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {...})
```

, not:

```
$("window").on('beforeunload', function() {...})
```

(no quotes around `window`). `$(window)` wraps the `window` javascript variable inside a jQuery object, where `$("window")` selects all `<window>` tags on the page, of which there are exactly 0.

(Most of the time. In fact you can do `$('body').append('<window></window>')`, and then `$("window")` matches that new tag - but don't do that.)