# How to disable the back button in the iPad's browser

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

Below is my code to detect and stop the browser's back button in iPad browsers.

```
$(window).bind("pagehide", function(e) { 
})
```

How can I stop the page going back on browsers' back button click in iPad browsers?

Comment: If you did this on a page I was visiting on my iPad, I would be very upset...

Comment: You could open the page in a different window/tab, which always disables the back button...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `onbeforeunload` event that triggers when a user is leaving your page, whether it's by hitting the back button, entering a new URL or closing the browser.

Here is an example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'You are leaving!?';
}
```

And here is the result on Chrome:

[image]

This event seems to be inconsistent across browsers as some will not support it, some will execute whatever function you pass it, and some will reject the function if it doesn't return a string to put in the confirmation box.

As commenter Alex Wayne stated, think twice about this. It can really create a negative impact on your site or webapp to alter the native behaviour of the back button.

Comment: window.onbeforeunload does not work with iPad browsers. Is there any alternative for the same.

Comment: The `onunload` event seems to be supported, which I believe is not what you want, but it's the closest to `onbeforeunload` you can get. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad#4824156

Comment: link to [window.onbeforeunload does not work with iPad browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad)