# Does jQuery .length defies DOM ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

Function `loader()` will keep running until `<body>` does exist. When `<body>` does exist, insert `.loader`

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    loader();
    function loader() {
        if (!$('body').length) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loader);
        } else {
            $('<div class="loader"></div>').prependTo('body');
        }
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- elements -->
</body>
</html>
```

I want to ask this line

```
if (!$('body').length) {}
```

What do `.length` use to determine its return, is it `<body>` or `<body></body>`? Does `.length` wait for closing tag `</body>` or not? If it does, what is my alternatives? I need `.loader` to be inserted without waiting for `</body>`.

My last resort would be

```
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <!-- rest of elements -->
</body>
```

So then

```
if (!$('.container').length) {}
```

But I need alternatives that don't interfere with the elements structure.

**EDIT:**

I rephrase the question and add below codes.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        console.log("ready timestamp");
    });
    loader();
    function loader() {
        if (!$('body').length) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loader);
        } else {
            console.log("length timestamp");
        }
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- elements -->
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
15:03:19.862 length timestamp
15:03:20.198 ready timestamp
```

Length timestamp always lower than ready timestamp.

Tested with:

Chrome 71.0 and FF 65.0

Enable timestamp in Console Settings (Developer Tools -> Console -> Show timestamps).

Other might ask why I did this, what's right about 300ms?

I implement PWA and need loader, like this:
[Showing loader while navigating between pages - PWA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951367/showing-loader-while-navigating-between-pages-pwa?rq=1).
The problem is, there is 300ms between `.on('beforeunload')` of the previous page and `$()` of the next page. It's a blip, obviously.

This blip can ideally/easily be solved by server side scripting but as I mentioned above, I have no access to server side scripting, the furthest I can ask is a blank element `<div class="container"></div>`.

Comment: why not use `$(function() {  $('<div class="loader"></div>').prependTo('body');  })` or `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // prepend to body }` ?

Comment: The body node starts existing at `<body>`, pretty much, but can you not put the script directly below `<body>`?

Comment: @NickParsons: I do above codes basically to avoid `.load()` or even `.ready()` . I need something earlier than `.ready()`.

Comment: @Ry-: I can not. Working with templates here, my hand tied with many ropes. The furthest I can go is adding `.container`

Comment: @Ry-: **The body node starts existing at <body>** . I need to confirm this. Can you provide me with some links? Been digging around but can't find any. Thanks.

Comment: `$('body')` finds the body Element in the DOM.  There is no closing tag at that point.  You're not dealing with HTML at that point.  You're dealing with the DOM.

Comment: The snippet in the question also has the issue of jQuery not being included in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran another test.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        console.log("ready timestamp");
    });
    loader_bottom();
    loader_body();
    loader_top();
    function loader_bottom() {
        if (!$('.container_bottom').length) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loader_bottom);
        } else {
            console.log("container_bottom.length timestamp");
        }
    };
    function loader_top() {
        if (!$('.container_top').length) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loader_top);
        } else {
            console.log("container_top.length timestamp");
        }
    };
    function loader_body() {
        if (!$('body').length) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loader_body);
        } else {
            console.log("body.length timestamp");
        }
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container_top"></div>
    <!-- elements between -->
    <div class="container_bottom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
09:09:16.894 body.length timestamp
09:09:16.897 container_top.length timestamp
09:09:17.090 container_bottom.length timestamp
09:09:17.220 ready timestamp
```

Because `$('.container_top')` adjacent to `$('body')`, changing the sequence,

```
loader_top();
loader_body();
```

Not suprisingly output:

```
09:09:39.708 container_top.length timestamp
09:09:39.708 body.length timestamp
```

Hence I come into conclusions:

1. Does jQuery `.length` defies DOM ready? Yes it does.
2. What do `.length` use to determine its return, is it `<body>` or `<body></body>`? It is `<body>`.

Although the right phrase for second question should be:
What DOM Parser use to determine nodes, is it `<tag>` or `<tag></tag>`? The answer is `<tag>`.

<del>Actually I'm not surprised that we can manipulate DOM before it's ready. Besides, `$().ready()` is just an event when DOM is ready. Javascript is multi-thread so (I thought) DOM Manipulating should could run parallel with DOM Parsing. Not until this code I can prove that.</del>

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log( $('#tryToFindMe').length );
</script>
<div id="tryToFindMe"></div>
```

Similar to how your question tries to access the body before it is defined, this snippet tries to access the div before it is defined.  In both cases, the element **will not** be found.

The reason for this is because when your browser is parsing your webpage into the Document Object Model it parses from top down.  So at the point that the script runs, the html that will create the div in the DOM has not been processed yet.  So the script tries to lookup the element, it does not exist, and the length is zero.

This is why using the jQuery document ready, binding to the DOMContentLoaded event or the load event exist.  These different approaches defer the execution of your logic until either the entire page has been parsed into the DOM, or in the case of load, that not only the page has been parsed into the DOM, but all the resources have been received as well (images, videos, etc). Without these approaches, the script will need to appear in the page after the element is defined to ensure the element exists already in the DOM.

The important part when thinking about interacting with the DOM is not to think in terms of HTML.  The DOM contains Nodes, not HTML.  The nodes are generated from the HTML.

Comment: I'm fully aware of that. That's why I have `window.requestAnimationFrame(loader);` in my script. It's almost the same as using `.setInterval()` to watch nodes existence but better.

Comment: That's unnecessary.  Document ready, DOMContentLoaded event, or the load event would all perform the same operation, without repeated executions before the element is available.  But aside from that, if you are aware of that, then I do not understand what your question is. @sangnandar

Comment: I try to manipulate the DOM before it's `$().ready()`. The reason I ask because I saw slight difference between above codes and `$().ready()`. I don't know whether it's just a glitch or maybe my PC is in a good mood or maybe the code is right. [link](https://api.jquery.com) said that `$('body').ready()` is incorrect, implies `$().ready()`, but how about `$('body').length` ? Is it really "THERE IS NOTHING BEFORE `$().ready()`" ?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){ /* your logic */ })` or `$(function(){ /* your logic */ })`is the correct format.  `ready()` executes on the document, not the body element.

Comment: I've rephrased the question and add some codes to show that my earlier code, using `.length`, do run before `$().ready()`.

Comment: I've already addressed in my answer about the `$('body').length`.  Body will not exist in the DOM until the page has processed all the html for it.

Comment: The fact that `.length` timestamp always lower than `.ready()` timestamp tells us otherwise, $('body') does exist before `.ready()`. I have 300-400 ms difference, local machine. The number is vary but the result is consistent.

Comment: I didn't say body will not exist before the ready fires.  I said body will not exist until the browser finishes processing "all of the html for it", meaning it reaches the `</body>`.  The ready() will fire once it finishes parsing the `</html>`.

Comment: Well...my test shows that `'body'` timestamp always lower than `.container_bottom` timestamp. Using the right execution sequence, `'body'` also lower than `.container_top`. These results can only be explained by `'body'`exist with `<body>` without waiting `</body>`

Comment: If that's true then it's possible that the browser is going ahead and attaching the element to the DOM while it is processing its children into it.

Comment: Indeed that's the intention of my script. I think you get my point now, why I use `window.requestAnimationFrame()` instead of `$()`. Alas, I'm more than happy if you could proved me wrong.

Comment: That being the case does not change my opinion about using `window.requestAnimationFrame()` to do the same thing that using a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener or document ready would do, with less iterations.  The difference between the time the requestAnimationFrame would cause your logic to execute vs when the document ready would are very small milliseconds.  It is highly unlikely that your application is millisecond critical, which would be the driving force to doing something like this rather than following community accepted best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a jQuery document ready function (`$(() => {})`) like so:

```
$(() => {
    $(`<div class="loader"></div>`).prependTo("body");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed @Taplar.