# LocalStorage does not work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, onload

I'm using localStorage to back up form data on a long form. So if a user refreshes they will not lose everything. This is working perfectly on Chrome & Firebox on the computer.

However on mobile (iOS at least) It's not working at all. Any advice?

Here is a small part of my code as an example:

## Storing Data:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
       window.localStorage.setItem("Job1", $("#topScore1B").text());
    }
```

## Retrieving Data:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //   If values are not blank, restore them to the fields
        var name = window.localStorage.getItem('Job1');
        if (name !== null) $('#job1').text(name);


}
```

Comment: Does it work if you set it during normal interaction rather than in `onbeforeunload`?

Comment: Are you using safari in incognito mode? The `setItem` will throw an exception if it is unable to write to localStorage, which is the case with incognito safari for example.

Comment: @Ryan If you're asking does the ID work in other uses then yes.

Comment: @Niklas It is not working in regular Safari

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi: I don’t know what “the ID” is, but if you use `setItem` in a click listener or something instead of `onbeforeunload`, are you able to read it with `getItem` on mobile?

Comment: @Ryan  Hmm no I cannot seem that to work on mobile either.

Comment: localStorage does indeed work on Android Chrome, iPad and maybe all mobile devices that run Chrome.  I've written this up with a plunkr code example you can point your device at and see it work : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833440/localstorage-is-null-in-chrome-mobile-android/56477550#56477550

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `beforeunload` event [does not fire on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3239834/201952).

It looks like `unload` *does* fire, so try storing your data into local storage there instead.

Alternatively, you could store data into local storage as the user edits the form (ie when each input fires `change`), which comes with the added bonus of storing the entered data even if the browser crashes before the user finishes.