# How can we detect in SignalR that disconnect has happened because of network or browser close etc?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am writing an asp.net mvc application and using SignalR to track simultaneous users.

How can we detect in SignalR that disconnect has happened because of network or browser close etc?

Thanks

Comment: The community will be able to help you if you show a sample of your code, explain what you've tried so far and the problems you're facing with the approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect answer but what i have done before is:

- Use the beforeunload JavaScript event to spot that the user is navigating away (note this doesn't work on all browsers - for an iPad you seem to have to use the pagehide event [window.onbeforeunload not working on the iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad)), and then nicely request SignalR stops
- Use the stopcalled parameter in the SignalR onDisconnected call back to spot whether it was shut down nicely or not (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)

The thing is, I've found its not perfect, but its the best bet that you have...