# Disconnect from server when tab is closed - React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mobile, socket.io

I am building a web app with **react**, **nodejs**, and **socket io**. I am using socket io so that the client can communicate with a node server. Currently, when a client closes the tab, a message is emitted to the server with the user's information so they server can do something with it. Currently, I am using *onPageHide* and *onBeforeUnload* to emit the message to the server. This works fine on desktop but on a mobile browser, these events aren't firing, so the message is not emitted to the server. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you in advance for all your help!

```
window.addEventListener("pagehide", () => {
  socket.emit("leftRoom", {
    lastTimeOnline: Date.now(),
  });

  socket.off();
});

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
  socket.emit("leftRoom", {
    lastTimeOnline: Date.now(),
  });

  socket.off();
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.onbeforeunload not working on the iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad)

Comment: No sorry. I tried this in the past but it didn't work for me.