# Wait the javascript code until the window closes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button, if user clicks on that button I am opening a external window as follows:

```
function btnClick(){

window.open("http://localhost/index.html");

/* I'LL WRITE SOME OTHER CODE AFTER THIS */

}
```

I want the javascript function to wait for that window to get closed before executing the rest of my code. Is there any way of doing that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291712/is-it-possible-to-open-a-popup-with-javascript-and-then-detect-when-the-user-clo

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the 'While' loop?

PS: I am a newbie, it is just a 'Maybe'.

EDIT:

```
      While (/*code for closing a window*/) {
      /*Function that you want to be executed after the 
      Window has been closed*/               
       };
```

You maybe also can do:

```
        If (/*window is closed code*/) {
       /*Code of Function etc*/
        };
```

Comment: What should he be testing in the `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
    function closingCode(){
       // do something...
       return null;
    }
```

A similar question which should help [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/how-to-run-javascript-code-on-window-close)

Answer (score 0):

There are two events named `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.onunload` that you can use to accomplish this: [JavaScript question: Onbeforeunload or Onunload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775566/javascript-question-onbeforeunload-or-onunload).