# $.post call is not happening in safari

Tags: jquery, post, safari

I am facing strange issue. when closing complete safari browser, I need to call one function using jquery post. but this is not calling when close safari browser. But beauty is working in all other browser.

Below is my piece of code,

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
   $.post("test.php");
}
</script>
```

Please kindly get this work in safari.

Thanks,
Dinesh Kumar Manoharan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be because you are doing an asynchronous post, and Safari stops running the JavaScript (due to the page being unloaded) before it issues the request. Try making the call blocking by using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of `$.post` and setting `async` to `false`.  Something like (untested):

```
function confirmExit() {
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': 'test.php'
    });
}
```

Comment: @Dinesh. No problem, and welcome to stackoverflow. Please remember to accept the answer that best solves your question (you can accept only one answer) and consider upvoting answers you found useful (you can upvote more than one answer).

Comment: why safari is developed this type of mistake? yet those fellows are not updated.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mozilla MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload), window.onbeforeunload won't return anything in Safari, so modify your code according to the linked example above.

There's another thread here on SO [about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158673/onbeforeunload-support-detection). Hope it helps.