# Ajax call only works when triggered manually in Safari but works fine in chrome

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Below is the code which is being used to make a request to an AJAX service, it currently works in chrome without any issues but fails with out any status's or error codes.

[AJAX request not working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGqE8.png)

[AJAX Resource panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehaax.png)

Response is set in the controller for the request

```
return response()->json(['hello' => $value])->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK, Response::$statusTexts[Response::HTTP_OK]);
```

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});


$(window).on('beforeunload ', function() {
  doLeavingAjax();
});

var currentPage = window.location.pathname;
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

function doLeavingAjax() {
  var endTime = new Date().getTime();
  var timeSpent = endTime - startTime;
  var i = 0;

  $.ajax({
    url: '/PSTracking/leave',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: 'false',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "timeSpent": timeSpent
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("_token", CSRF_TOKEN);
    }

  });
  return false;

}

<
/script>
```

Comment: Is the call making it to the backend at all?

Comment: @Samsquanch in chrome it shows in the logs but it doesn't even hit the log in safari.

Comment: If you change `async: 'false',` to `async: false,`, does that change anything? Your issue looks similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548505/post-call-is-not-happening-in-safari).